# how to get prometheus webflux r2dbc in spring work together? It gives me error when I try to run actual apis from service

Tags: spring, prometheus, spring-webflux, r2dbc

I am generating metrics using prometheus in spring-boot2 and I am using webflux and r2dbc lib for reactive programming, however I am not sure if these works together. Please help me to understand what i am doing wrong.

It gives following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.reactive.TransactionSynchronizationManager.currentTransaction()Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:88) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.0.0.M2.jar:1.0.0.M2]   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
 plugins {    
        id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE",
        id ("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
     }
   dependencies {
       implementation ("org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-r2dbc")
       implementation ("org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
       implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
       implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
       implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
       implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
       testImplementation ("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
  }
```

Controller function look like this:

```
@Timed(histogram = true )
@GetMapping("/abc")
fun process(@PathVariable ab: String): Mono<xyz> {
    return service.getXYZ(xyz)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when generating a new project using the spring initializer it will provide you with the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-r2dbc'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

Seems lite you are missing the `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-r2dbc`, and you can remove

```
implementation ("org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-r2dbc")
```

Since the `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` will pull in its transitive dependencies.

As R2DBC is still experimental, its autoconfiguration has not been merged into spring boot yet and must be included separately. I have opened an issue to the developers and requested that as of now this part should be mentioned in the official docs.